# How to get one result from a table and several from another with the same catID?

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to build a forum of a kind i dont know. Just fooling around with some code.

And now i got two tables, the first with the forum categories and the second with forum boards.

My question now is, can i use LEFT JOIN or any join to take one of each from the categories table and all the result with the same catID from boards?

This is my right now none working code:

```
$query = $_database->query("
SELECT boards.name AS boardName, boards.info, boards.category, boards.boardID, boards.sort, boards.topics, boards.posts,
categories.catID, categories.name AS catName, categories.sort 
FROM ".PREFIX."forum_boards AS boards LEFT JOIN ".PREFIX."forum_categories AS categories ON boards.category = categories.catID GROUP BY categories.catID ORDER BY boards.boardID");
while ($rad = $query->fetch_array()) {
    echo '<h2>'.$rad['catName'].'</h2>';
    echo $rad['boardName'];
}
```

Got a request to post my table structure and here it is

Boards:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mm_forum_boards` (
`boardID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `info` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sort` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `topics` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `posts` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Categories:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mm_forum_categories` (
`catID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `info` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sort` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Some data:

```
INSERT INTO mm_forum_categories (`name`, `info`, `sort`) VALUES('Test Cat 1', 'Just giving some lorem data ^^', '1');
INSERT INTO mm_forum_categories (`name`, `info`, `sort`) VALUES('Test Cat 2', 'Just giving some lorem data ^^', '2');
INSERT INTO mm_forum_boards (`category`, `name`, `info`, sort`) VALUES('3', 'Test board 1', 'Lorem board for now', '1');
INSERT INTO mm_forum_boards (`category`, `name`, `info`, sort`) VALUES('3', 'Test board 2', 'Lorem board for now', '2');
INSERT INTO mm_forum_boards (`category`, `name`, `info`, sort`) VALUES('3', 'Test board 3', 'Lorem board for now', '3');

INSERT INTO mm_forum_boards (`category`, `name`, `info`, sort`) VALUES('4', 'Test board 4', 'Lorem board for now', '1')
```

Comment: Can you post your table structure and some test / sample data?

Comment: I have made an edit on my post with the table structure.

Comment: What does it mean, that you select is not working? Syntax error, no result, wrong results?

Comment: He gets the row from categories, but not the boards for that category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` clause in the SQL is wrong here. It aggregeates all rows with the same category_id. This is useful when you want to count them, but not here.

When you want to order by the category, put it in the `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: Removed it now, and set the order by instead.
BUT i have 3 boards in cat 1 
And now it gives me three h2 tags aswell, i only want one

Comment: SQL always returns (two-dimensional) tables with rows. 
So you need either aggregrate them in PHP 
or use a SQL query for the categories and then inside the loop SQL queries to get the board for the category.

Comment: So i need to make two queries?

Comment: Not nessesary. As said, there are different ways two solve it. You can use php and only display a category header when it is different than the row before. I think you can solve this by yourself if you try. If not, that would be another question.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this below Query

```
SELECT
  mm_forum_categories.name,
  mm_forum_categories.info,
  mm_forum_boards.name,
  mm_forum_boards.info,
  mm_forum_boards.sort,
  mm_forum_boards.topics
FROM
  mm_forum_categories
LEFT Join mm_forum_boards 
  ON mm_forum_categories.catID = mm_forum_boards.category
WHERE
  mm_forum_categories.catID =  '1'
```

I think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need a simple `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`. Have a look at this query.

```
SELECT mfc.name AS cat_name, mfc.catID as catID
FROM mm_forum_categories mfc
RIGHT OUTER JOIN mm_forum_boards 
ON mfc.catID = mm_forum_boards.category;
```

Comment: A Right Outer Join is the same as Left Outer Join with the order of the tables exchanged. Normally it confuses things more than it helps.